# Is there an event handler which raises when a ressource is assigned, changed or removed in Project Server?

Tags: c#, eventhandler, project-server, ms-project-server-2013

I need to be able to do some job when a ressource is assigned, removed from or changed within a task in Microsoft Project Server.

I have read the following article on creating an Event Handler:

[How to: Create a Project Server Event Handler and Log an Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615466(v=office.14).aspx)

I wanted to know if there is an event which is fired when a ressource is assigned, removed or changed for a task within Project Server or a task is created within a project with a resource assigned?

Maybe someone could provide an example on this?

best regards

Bog

Comment: Isnt this technically possible? Isnt there any event which catches the above function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this article from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.project.server.events.resourceeventreceiver_di_pj14mref_members.aspx) , the answer is yes

You might be interested in the following events

- `OnActivating`:  A pre-event handler for the `ActivateResources` method.
- `OnSettingAuthorization`:    A pre-event handler for the `SetResourceAuthorization` method.
- `OnChanging`  :  A pre-event handler for the `UpdateResources` method.
- `OnCreating`  :  A pre-event handler for the `CreateResources` method.
- `OnDeleting`  :  A pre-event handler for the `DeleteResources` method.

also you can access the `OnActivated`, `OnSetAuthorization` , `OnChanged`, `OnCreated`, `OnDeleted` as well

Hope this will help you